# OpenApi 3 not able to import schemas present at remote location or as external files

Tags: api, rest, web-services, swagger, openapi

I am trying to use open API 3.0 specification to define API contracts using swagger Hub. Happy scenarios work really well where all the components like schemas, examples, and responses are able to import locally using the **$ref** keyword.

Now thinking of a broader perspective I idea was to externalize all components so that in the future all the components (schema, responses, etc.) are available to reference in any of the API documentation and prevent repetitive work and bring consistency.

Unfortunately, the $ref is not working while pointing to a remote folder or external reference like GIT.

As per the documentation mentioned below, it should work/
*https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/*

At some place YAML file. :-

```html
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Author-Lifecycle-APIs
  description: This APIs manage all the different operations related to Author lifecycle
  contact:
    email: abcxyz@gmail.com
tags:
  - name: Author Master
    description: Everything related to an Author lifecycle
paths:
  /author:
    get:
      summary: Find all the authors detail
      description: This provide author basic details for all the authors records present in the database.
      operationId: getAuthors
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successfully able to fetch authors details
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Author'
              examples:
                author:
                  $ref: '#/components/examples/Author'
        '400':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/BadRequest'
        '404':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/NotFound'
    post:
      summary: Save a new author record into the database.
      operationId: saveBook
      requestBody:
        $ref: '#/components/requestBodies/Author'
      responses:
        '201':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/Created'
        '400':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/BadRequest'       
servers:
  # Added by API Auto Mocking Plugin
  - description: SwaggerHub API Auto Mocking
    url: https://virtserver.swaggerhub.com/KINIPOC/Author-Lifecycle/1.0.0
components:
  ## Reusable Schemas/Models ##
  schemas:
    Author:
      description: This is the schema defination for author model
      type: object
      required:
        - authorName
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          example: 12345
          readOnly: true
        authorName:
          type: string
          example: Robert
    Error:
      type: object
      properties:
        code:
          type: string
        message:
          type: string
      required:
        - code
        - message
  ## Reusable Examples Schemas/Models ##
  examples:
    Author:
      summary: example of author schema
      value:
       - id : 1
         authorName: Robert
       - id : 2
         authorName: Gopal Das      
  ## Reusable Responses ##       
  responses:
    NotFound:
      description: The specified resource was not found
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
          example:
            code: 404
            message: The server can not find the requested resource.  
    Unauthorized:
      description: Unauthorized
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
          example:
            code: 401
            message: The user is not authorized to access the requested resource.  
    BadRequest:
      description: Request is not correct
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
          example:
            code: 400
            message: The request is not correct.
    Created:
      description: Data is successfully saved into the DB.
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
          example:
            code: 201
            message: Record is successfully created into the DB. 
  # Reusable Request Body
  requestBodies:
    Author:
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Author'
      description: Author object that needs to be added to the database.
      required: true
```

When I am trying to use the Error schema of other API spec as I don't want to bring duplicate schemas it is not working

```
BadRequest:
  description: Request is not correct
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        **$ref: '/../../KUNIPOC-Book-Lifecycle-1.0.4-swagger.yaml#/components/schemas/Error'**
      example:
        code: 400
        message: The request is not correct.
```

Error :- While saving in swagger hub it gives integration error.

Instead of using .. to refer remote file tried with absolute URL and it was able to read the YAML file as no 404 error was shown which was there when I deliberately put the incorrect file name but still the content of the YAML files are not accessible.

```
BadRequest:
  description: Request is not correct
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        $ref: 'https://virtserver.swaggerhub.com/KUPOC/Book-Lifecycle/1.0.1#/components/schemas/Error'
      example:
        code: 400
        message: The request is not correct.
```

Same exercise I tried with GIT URL and it was able to point the YAML or JSON file on GIT but not able to read the content of YAML file

```
Created:
  description: Data is successfully saved into the DB.
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        $ref: 'https://github.com/katcs/swaggerdocdemo/blob/main/book.yaml#/components/schemas/Error'
      example:
        code: 201
        message: Record is successfully created into the DB.
```

Any inputs here are highly appreciated !!

Comment: In SwaggerHub, you are supposed to use [domains](https://support.smartbear.com/swaggerhub/docs/domains/index.html) to store common components.

Comment: Thanks, @Helen. It was a silly mistake even after I was aware of this :D